# How do I select rows from a table if I know value in another table but not ID?

Tags: mysql, join

I have this table structure (I made it myself, it is free to say if you think it is bad and give better example)
[image: Tables]
Several images can be found in one room which is mapped in the table image_room. Image_room looks like

```
image_id | room_id
    1 | 1
    2 | 1
    3 | 1
    4 | 2
    5 | 3
    6 | 4
```

Room with id 1 contains three images

I know guid from room table. How do I select all the image_name in a room based on the GUID number I know in MySQL?

Eg I know the guid XXX. With a select I want to find out that XXX has room_id 1 in the room table. My map table says that images 1, 2 and 3 are in that room.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try below:

```
select image_name from image where image_id in (select image_id from image_room where room_id in (select room_id from room where room_guid = 'xxx'))
```

Answer (score 1):

The normal way to do this would use an explicit `join`:

```
select i.image_name
from room r inner join
     image_room ir
     on r.room_id = ir.room_id inner join
     image i
     on ir.image_id = i.image_id
where r.guid = @GUID;
```

You should declare your `id` columns to be primary keys, probably auto-incremented primary keys, for better performance.